# Does WCF serialize the data in the db before the jump, and where does it deserialize?

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, serialization, wireshark

I'm debugging a WCF-only issue in a ~2mil lines of codebase that I'm pretty new on.

We've determined that the data in the Oracle db is good data, and a few layers up from the db we have found bad data. The Data Access layer and a service layer or two are hosted somewhere and running them locally to debug is difficult, so I wanted to see the data go from the db to the DA layer.

I'm running Wireshark and captured the packets coming from my remote db, i installed the SSL cert, the lines are black so I think that means it decrypted it correctly, but all I'm seeing is gibberish in the Follow TCP Stream menu.

So am I ever going to see good data going over the wire from the db to the Data Access layer? Does WCF serialize it BEFORE the jump, then deserialize it somewhere in the mystery-box DA/Services layer?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You might be thinking about the wrong "layer" here (or I am, not unlikely). For example, I've used a service that uses `BasicHttpBinding` which uses "HTTP as the transport" with "a "Text" message encoding and UTF-8 text encoding by default.", but I could also choose `NetTcpBinding` which "uses TCP for message delivery, and a binary message encoding" - these should show up differently in wireshark despite transmitting the same serialized data.

Comment: The service will serialize the data on send and deserialize on receive, and the client will operate in the same manner.  If the data is good in the DB, then you need to work your way up the stack to see if it's getting mangled in one of the layers - maybe a translation/mapping error?

Comment: Instead of Wireshark try [Microsoft Message Analizer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226) I had to use it to look at some packets that where in a SSL stream for a Sql TDS stream and it worked great. Built in support for SOAP messages (which is what WCF is sending and receiving) is provided.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help guys, after running both Wireshark and Microsoft Message Analizer at the suggestion of @ScottChamberlain we have discovered that the serializer actually serializes it before it goes over the wire from the db to the Data Access layer, then deserializes at the Service layer. This was confirmed by a senior dev over here, and this all works this way only because that is how our specific SOAP-based service architecture works.

So for those looking for an answer, it depends on your WCF serializer implementation, but this is probably how yours works. Ours, and possibly yours, work like this:

1. The service tells the db to serialize the data
2. The db sends back a bytecode stream
3. The service layer deserializes the data

Hopefully this helps someone out there trying to debug this layer.